# Print result over a div

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to print the result of my query into a div that is called in other file of my proyect. thefile where i have the resulta is called `chat.php` and is called from `index.php` how can i print the result into div`chat`

this is my code from chat.php

```
<?php session_start();

include 'db.php';
require_once '../functions.php';

comprobarSession(); 
$id=$_GET['id'];
//var_dump($id)
?>

<?php 

$sql = "SELECT ue.nombre de, ur.nombre a, c.message FROM  messages c
        INNER JOIN usuarios ue ON c.idEmitter = ue.idUsuario
        INNER JOIN usuarios ur ON c.idReceiver = ur.idUsuario
        WHERE (c.idEmitter = :usr1 AND c.idReceiver = :usr2)
        OR (c.idEmitter = :usr2 AND c.idReceiver = :usr1)
        ORDER BY sent ASC";

$usr1=$id;
$usr2=$us;

$stmt = $conexion->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam("usr1",$usr1);
$stmt->bindParam("usr2",$usr2);
$stmt ->execute();
$arrDatos = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//var_dump($arrDatos);
imprimir ($arrDatos);

$pdo = null;

?>

<?php 
//Una función para mostrar los datos
function imprimir($arrDatos)
{

    if ($arrDatos)
    {
        echo "<hr />SE ENCONTRARON  ".count($arrDatos). " REGISTROS<br /><hr />";
        /**
         *  Construímos los datos  de forma limpia
        */
        $strHtml='CHAT:<br />';    
        foreach ($arrDatos as $row)
        {
            //'<div id="chat_data">'
            $strHtml.='<span style="color: green;>'.$row["de"].': </span>'.$row["message"].'<br />';
            $strHtml.='<span style="color: green;>'.$row["a"].': </span>'.$row["message"].'<br />';
            //'</div>'
        }
        echo $strHtml;
    }
}
?>
```

and this one of index.php

```
<?php session_start();

include 'db.php';
include '../functions.php';

$emit = obtener_mensajes($conexion, $us);

comprobarSession();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script>
        function ajax(){
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById('chat').innerHTML = req.responseText;
                }
            }

            var myId = document.getElementById('myId');
            var url = 'chat.php?id='+myId;

            req.open('POST', url, true);
            req.send();

        }

        setInterval(function(){
            ajax()
        }, 1000);
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="ajax();">

<div id="container">
    <div id="chat_box">
        <div id="chat">HERE IS WHERE CHAT.PHP NEED TO BE</div>
    </div>
    <form action="index.php" method="POST">
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Enter message"></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="nombre" placeholder="Name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['usuario']['nombre']?>">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send it">
        <?php foreach ($emit as $msg): ?>   
        <input type="hidden" id="myId" name="idReceiver" value="<?php echo $msg['idEmitter']; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="idEmitter" value="<?php echo $us ?>">
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </form>
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['nombre'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $emitter = $_POST['idEmitter'];
    $receiver = $_POST['idReceiver'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO messages (nombre, message, idEmitter, idReceiver, seenUsuario) VALUES ('$name', '$message', '$emitter', '$receiver', '0')";

    $run = $conexion->query($query);
}

?>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

> **Edition**

this is what print when i chang the code 
[image]

functions is a file that are in the principal folder

[image]

Comment: what's wrong with a simple include?

Comment: nope, if i put an include this print some errors

Comment: probably because of the relative routes in it, still it's the easiest one to implement by the look of your code.

Comment: @LordNeo and how can i implement, i'm new using javascript and ajax like this

Comment: Remove ´session_start(); include 'db.php'; require_once '../functions.php';´ from chat.php and then use include in the index.php, that should do it.

Comment: @LordNeo if i do that show me more errors `Notice: Undefined variable: us in C:\xampp\htdocs\talvez empresa\chat\chat.php on line 17

Notice: Undefined variable: conexion in C:\xampp\htdocs\talvez empresa\chat\chat.php on line 19

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\talvez empresa\chat\chat.php:19 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\talvez empresa\chat\chat.php on line 19`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150030/discussion-between-lordneo-and-cesar-gutierrez-davalos).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Answer (score 0):

Content of chat.php

```
<?php 
$id=$_GET['id'];
//var_dump($id)
?>

<?php 

$sql = "SELECT ue.nombre de, ur.nombre a, c.message FROM  messages c
        INNER JOIN usuarios ue ON c.idEmitter = ue.idUsuario
        INNER JOIN usuarios ur ON c.idReceiver = ur.idUsuario
        WHERE (c.idEmitter = :usr1 AND c.idReceiver = :usr2)
        OR (c.idEmitter = :usr2 AND c.idReceiver = :usr1)
        ORDER BY sent ASC";

$usr1=$id;
$usr2=$us;

$stmt = $conexion->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam("usr1",$usr1);
$stmt->bindParam("usr2",$usr2);
$stmt ->execute();
$arrDatos = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//var_dump($arrDatos);
imprimir ($arrDatos);

$pdo = null;

//Una función para mostrar los datos
function imprimir($arrDatos)
{

    if ($arrDatos)
    {
        echo "<hr>SE ENCONTRARON  ".count($arrDatos). " REGISTROS<br><hr>";
        /**
         *  Construímos los datos  de forma limpia
        */
        $strHtml='CHAT:<br>';    
        foreach ($arrDatos as $row)
        {
            //'<div id="chat_data">'
            $strHtml.='<span style="color: green;>'.$row["de"].':
                       </span>'.$row["message"].'<br />';
            $strHtml.='<span style="color: green;>'.$row["a"].':
                       </span>'.$row["message"].'<br />';
            //'</div>'
        }
        echo $strHtml;
    }
}
?>
```

Content of index.php

```
<?php session_start();

include 'db.php';
include '../functions.php';

$emit = obtener_mensajes($conexion, $us);

comprobarSession();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script>
        function ajax(){
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById('chat')
                    .innerHTML =req.responseText;
                }
            }

            var myId = document.getElementById('myId');
            var url = 'chat.php?id='+myId;

            req.open('POST', url, true);
            req.send();

        }

        setInterval(function(){
            ajax()
        }, 1000);
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="ajax();">

<div id="container">
    <div id="chat_box">
        <div id="chat"><?php include("chat.php");?></div>
    </div>
    <form action="index.php" method="POST">
        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Enter message"></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="nombre" placeholder="Name" value="
        <?php echo $_SESSION['usuario']['nombre']?>">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send it">
        <?php foreach ($emit as $msg): ?>   
        <input type="hidden" id="myId" name="idReceiver" value="
        <?php echo $msg['idEmitter']; ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="idEmitter" value="<?php echo $us ?>">
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </form>
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['nombre'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $emitter = $_POST['idEmitter'];
    $receiver = $_POST['idReceiver'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO messages (nombre, message, idEmitter, 
         idReceiver, seenUsuario) VALUES ('$name', '$message', '$emitter', 
         '$receiver', '0')";

    $run = $conexion->query($query);
}

?>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This should work as intended considering that chat.php and index.php are on the same folder and the routes to db.php and functions.php are fine.

Comment: i edit my question with the resulto of your solution