# send form with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to sen my form with ajax but this doens't do anything

this is my form

```
<form method="POST" onsubmit="return enviar();">
        <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Enter message"></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['usuario']['nombre']?>">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send it">

        <input type="hidden" id="myId" name="idReceiver" value="<?php echo $id ?>">
        <input type="hidden" id="idEmitter" name="idEmitter" value="<?php echo $us ?>">
    </form>
```

and this is my function

```
function enviar(){
            var mensaje = document.getElementById('message').value;
            var nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
            var idEmitter = document.getElementById('myId').value;
            var idReceiver = document.getElementById('idEmitter').value;

            var dataen = 'message='+mensaje +'&nombre='+nombre +'&myId='+idEmitter +'&idEmitter='+idReceiver;

            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                dataType: "html",
                url:'inser.php',
                data:dataen
            });
            return false;
        }
```

and this one is inser.php (i wrote correct)

```
<?php 

include 'db.php';
include '../functions.php';

var_dump($_POST);

    $name = $_POST['nombre'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $emitter = $_POST['idEmitter'];
    $receiver = $_POST['idReceiver'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO messages (nombre, message, idEmitter, idReceiver, seenUsuario) VALUES ('$name', '$message', '$emitter', '$receiver', '0')";

    $run = $conexion->query($query);


?>
```

i wont this because i don't want to refresh my page when i make click on my button, if i get inside from inser.php when i make submit i get this errors

```
array(0) { }
Notice: Undefined index: nombre in C:\xampp\htdocs\talvez empresa\chat\inser.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: message in C:\xampp\htdocs\talvez empresa\chat\inser.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined index: idEmitter in C:\xampp\htdocs\talvez empresa\chat\inser.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined index: idReceiver in C:\xampp\htdocs\talvez empresa\chat\inser.php on line 11
```

how can i make this? i have another functions

this is my complete script

```
<script>
        function enviar(){
            var mensaje = document.getElementById('message').value;
            var nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
            var idEmitter = document.getElementById('myId').value;
            var idReceiver = document.getElementById('idEmitter').value;

            var dataen = 'message='+mensaje +'&nombre='+nombre +'&myId='+idEmitter +'&idEmitter='+idReceiver;

            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                dataType: "html",
                url:'inser.php',
                data:dataen
            });
            return false;
        }

        function getPage(url, from, to) {
            var cached=sessionStorage[url];
            if(!from){from="body";} // default to grabbing body tag
            if(to && to.split){to=document.querySelector(to);} // a string TO turns into an element
            if(!to){to=document.querySelector(from);} // default re-using the source elm as the target elm
            if(cached){return to.innerHTML=cached;} // cache responses for instant re-use re-use

            var XHRt = new XMLHttpRequest; // new ajax
            XHRt.responseType='document';  // ajax2 context and onload() event
            XHRt.onload= function() { sessionStorage[url]=to.innerHTML= XHRt.response.querySelector(from).innerHTML;};
            XHRt.open("GET", url, true);
            XHRt.send();
            return XHRt;
        }

        window.onload(function() {
            setInterval(function(){
            var myId = document.getElementById("myId");
            var url = 'chat.php?id='+myId;
            getPage(url, "body", "chat");
            }, 1000);
        })
    </script>
```

> **EDITION OF ANSWER**

in my URL is like this

> http://localhost/talvez%20empresa/chat/index.php?id=4

the id 4 or x value of id, is required to the correct function of my "chat" because of this is how i can take the messages

when i make a submit with the knew answer of @Rex Martinus

the URL change to these

> http://localhost/talvez%20empresa/chat/index.php?message=asd&nombre=Demon+Tech+System&submit=Send+it&idReceiver=4&idEmitter=3

so this disappear the id on the URL and show this erros

[image]

> **DataBase**

this is how the DB shows

[image]

in these moment `$id` is the 4 it doesn't matter if is the receiver or the Emitter, in my query search for both

and the `$us` is the number 3, is the same in the query

> **WHAT I HAD BEFORE TO REFRESH**

```
function ajax(){
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById('chat').innerHTML = req.responseText;
                }
            }

            var myId = document.getElementById('myId');
            var url = 'chat.php?id='+myId;

            req.open('POST', url, true);
            req.send();

        }

        setInterval(function(){
            ajax()
        }, 1000);
```

> **WITH NEW ANSWER**

[image]

> **Edition actual code**

index.php

```
    <?php session_start();

include 'db.php';
include '../functions.php';

$emit = obtener_mensajes($conexion, $us);
$id=$_GET['id'];
var_dump($id);

comprobarSession();

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/functions.js">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <div id="chat_box">
        <div id="chat"><?php require_once 'chat.php'; ?></div>
    </div>
    <form id="form">
        <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Enter message"></textarea>
        <input type="hidden" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['usuario']['nombre']?>">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send it" id="submit">

        <input type="hidden" id="myId" name="idReceiver" value="<?php echo $id ?>">
        <input type="hidden" id="idEmitter" name="idEmitter" value="<?php echo $us ?>">
    </form>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

functions.js

```
function getPage(url, from, to) {
    var cached=sessionStorage[url];
    if(!from){from="body";} // default to grabbing body tag
    if(to && to.split){to=document.querySelector(to);} // a string TO turns into an element
    if(!to){to=document.querySelector(from);} // default re-using the source elm as the target elm
    if(cached){return to.innerHTML=cached;} // cache responses for instant re-use re-use

    var XHRt = new XMLHttpRequest; // new ajax
    XHRt.responseType='document';  // ajax2 context and onload() event
    XHRt.onload= function() { sessionStorage[url]=to.innerHTML= XHRt.response.querySelector(from).innerHTML;};
    XHRt.open("GET", url, true);
    XHRt.send();
    return XHRt;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','#submit',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var dataen = $("#form").serialize() + "&action";// the action here is for if(isset($_POST['action'])){do this}

            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'inser.php',
                data:dataen
            });
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','#submit',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var dataen = $("#form").serialize() + "&action";// the action here is for if(isset($_POST['action'])){do this}

            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'inser.php',
                data:dataen
            });
    });
});
```

chat.php

```
<?php

$id=$_GET['id'];

$sql = "SELECT ue.nombre de, ur.nombre a, c.message FROM  messages c
        INNER JOIN usuarios ue ON c.idEmitter = ue.idUsuario
        INNER JOIN usuarios ur ON c.idReceiver = ur.idUsuario
        WHERE (c.idEmitter = $id AND c.idReceiver = $us)
        OR (c.idEmitter = $us AND c.idReceiver = $id)
        ORDER BY sent ASC";

$stmt = $conexion->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$arrDatos = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
imprimir($arrDatos);

//Una función para mostrar los datos
function imprimir($arrDatos)
{
    if ($arrDatos)
    {
        /**
         *  Construímos los datos  de forma limpia
        */
        $strHtml='CHAT:<br>';    
        foreach ($arrDatos as $row)
        {
            $strHtml.='<span style="color: green;>'.$row["a"].': </span>'.'<br>'.$row["message"].'<br>';
            $strHtml.='<span style="color: green;>'.$row["de"].': </span>'.'<br>'.$row["message"].'<br>';
        }
        echo $strHtml;
    }
}
?>
```

inser.php

```
<?php 

include 'db.php';
include '../functions.php';

if (isset($_POST['action'])) {

$name = $_POST['nombre'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$emitter = $_POST['idEmitter'];
$receiver = $_POST['idReceiver'];
echo "name:".$name." message:".$message." emitter:".$emitter." receiver:".$receiver;


$query = "INSERT INTO messages (nombre, message, idEmitter, idReceiver, seenUsuario) VALUES ('$name', '$message', '$emitter', '$receiver', '0')";

$run = $conexion->query($query);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chat"><!-- Where the chat shows --></div>
<form id="form">
    <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Enter message"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Name" value="usuario nombre">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send it" id="submit">

    <input type="hidden" id="myId" name="idReceiver" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" id="idEmitter" name="idEmitter" value="2">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    ajaxcall();
    $(document).on('click','#submit',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var dataen = $("#form").serialize() + "&action";// the action here is for if(isset($_POST['action'])){do this}

            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'inser.php',
                data:dataen,
                success:function(response){
                    if (response == "") {}
                    alert(response);
                    ajaxcall();
                }
            });
    });
});
    // Calls read.php file
    function ajaxcall(){

    var myId = document.getElementById('myId').value;// the $us
    $.ajax({
        url: 'chat.php?id='+myId,// url where you will get the data
        success: function(data) {//  means if success do this
                $('#chat').html(data);// id of the element that the data will be shown
            }
        });
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

inser.php

```
<?php 

include 'db.php';
include '../functions.php';

if (isset($_POST['action'])) {

$name = $_POST['nombre'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$emitter = $_POST['idEmitter'];
$receiver = $_POST['idReceiver'];
echo "name:".$name." message:".$message." emitter:".$emitter." receiver:".$receiver;


$query = "INSERT INTO messages (nombre, message, idEmitter, idReceiver, seenUsuario) VALUES ('$name', '$message', '$emitter', '$receiver', '0')";

$run = $conexion->query($query);
}
?>
```

See here [Jquery .serialize()](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

Comment: look i put my code in the cloud [https://mega.nz/#!DlVU2SQI!4pTf20qUVo1xikWhhseeDw1XTXvQKtha4p8iu6SjWoI]

Comment: @CesarGutierrezDavalos did you put `<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>` on the `<head>` of the html?

Comment: can you send me your database

Comment: look i share the complete project and db, In the end it's just test [mega.nz/#!S1Nz0ZxD!e8_X8OLFen55-tXzTJAf63lCRoyOVW53rUJg6cQ9J‌​a4] the user is cesg.dav@hotmail.com and pass cesar

Comment: please help me haha, this is just what i need to finish my project :'(

Comment: @CesarGutierrezDavalos are you still there?

Comment: @CesarGutierrezDavalos did you try my new answer?

Comment: i try your new solution, and in inser.php is all like if it insert on the db but it does't, and in index, put all in the URL so this make that the principal id dissapear and print errors

Comment: have you try with the answer of Arun? i try but to me doesn't work or, probably i make it wrong :/ probably is my second haha

Comment: is your database connection successful?

Comment: @CesarGutierrezDavalos can you show me the error when you use my new answer?

Comment: i'm going to put the imagein a edition on my question

Comment: @CesarGutierrezDavalos Where does the id come from?

Comment: @CesarGutierrezDavalos are you trying to get $id=$_GET['id'];? What is stored in $id?

Comment: the id comes when i click on the 'notification' that appears in the folder views/mensajes.view.php

Comment: what do you mean with the question?

Comment: is it a session or not?

Comment: if its not you have to make the url index.php?id={your id}

Comment: yes, the variable $us is the id of the user that login

Comment: but the variable $id is the person that send the message, if you check the db the id 4 in messages, is about the Emiter

Comment: the $id is the that will send the message or the one who will receive the message or is it vice versa

Comment: the $id is the one who will send the message?is it?

Comment: nope, well realtive yes, look i have to types of users, enterprise and user the $id is from the user and the $us is from the enterprise, what $id do is that when the query starts find the idEmitter and idReceiver and print the query result into the chat i hope make me explain

Comment: sorry Im just reading your empleos.sql because my database says  Can't create table `empleos`.`mensajes` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"), I use xampp

Comment: so the $id is the user id and the $us is you enterprise. so who is the enterprise is it you?

Comment: yes i'm the enterprise in these moment i'm going to put a screen shot of how the table messages looks

Comment: try to use again my answer and tell me what happened

Comment: these change the URL `http://localhost/talvez%20empresa/chat/index.php?message=asdasd&nombre=Demon+Tech+System&submit=Send+it&idReceiver=1&idEmitter=3` and doesnt send anything into te db

Comment: Please do not give up haha ​​I just need this to finish it

Comment: `http://localhost/talvez%20empresa/chat/index.php?message=asd‌​asd&nombre=Demon+Tec‌​h+System&submit=Send‌​+it&idReceiver=1&idE‌​mitter=3` this the link when you submit the form? try the script I have given

Comment: these insert into the database! but, doesn't show instantly into the the chat

Comment: @CesarGutierrezDavalos so Its like the user is sending a message to the admin or the owner of the that website

Comment: @CesarGutierrezDavalos what is your script to show the chat?

Comment: previusly i have something that i just put in my question but i remove

Comment: @CesarGutierrezDavalos do the things I change in my answer

Comment: that make a refres into chat.php, and make that the id desappear into chat.php so these make an error

Comment: did you put an  `id="form"` in the form?

Comment: when you submit the url change to this`http://localhost/talvez%20empresa/chat/index.php?message=asd‌​‌​asd&nombre=Demon+T‌​ec‌​h+System&submit=‌​Send‌​+it&idReceiver‌​=1&idE‌​mitter=3`?

Comment: no, when i say that refresh chat.php makes that the id, and the $us, doesnt work see the  new image

Comment: i don't know what you mean with check.php, i doesn't have any file with that name

Comment: sorry I mean chat.php, chat.php is the one that gets the chat right?

Comment: yeah, this is where i print all the conversation

Comment: does the myId input has a value did you check try to alert it if it don't have try to use this `var myId = document.getElementById('myId').value;`

Comment: well that code that i put, is about a very long changes haha https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45288993/print-result-over-a-div?noredirect=1#comment77542188_45288993

Comment: try the answer I recently change

Comment: this change th URL `http://localhost/talvez%20empresa/chat/index.php?message=Prueba+envio+nuevo+refresh%21&nombre=Demon+Tech+System&submit=Send+it&idReceiver=1&idEmitter=3`

Comment: in cosole don't show an error but remember, if the URL it's change the chat fails

Comment: well, i put somethings that i didn't see and these make all crashes

Comment: WEIT a sec this works but the message just show because the alert shows

Comment: is the function getpage() shows the chat? try to change that to my function ajaxcall() that function will call the `chat.php?id=myId` and will show to `<div id="chat"></div>`

Comment: yup, that works, when i send a message this throw the alert of success and show the new message, but if i remove the success, the message doesn't appear

Comment: the success your saying is the success:function()?

Comment: try to use jquery ajax than the traditional ajax xmlhttprequest its more shorter and easier to do

Comment: don't remove that try this `success:function(response){
                    if (response == "") {
                        ajaxcall();
                    }
                }`

Comment: @CesarGutierrezDavalos use the `function ajaxcall(){

    var myId = document.getElementById('myId').value;// the $us
    $.ajax({
        url: 'chat.php?id='+myId,// url where you will get the data
        success: function(data) {//  means if success do this
                $('#chat').html(data);// id of the element that the data will be shown
            }
        });
    }`

Comment: @CesarGutierrezDavalos Im happy because I help you solve your problem.

Comment: men really, you are my new inspiration

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150068/discussion-between-rex-martinus-and-cesar-gutierrez-davalos).

Comment: Thank you @CesarGutierrezDavalos

Answer (score 0):

Give you form an id, something like this should work

```
<form method="POST" id="my-form"">
    <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Enter message"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Name"
           value="<?php echo $_SESSION['usuario']['nombre'] ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send it">

    <input type="hidden" id="myId" name="idReceiver" value="<?php echo $id ?>">
    <input type="hidden" id="idEmitter" name="idEmitter" value="<?php echo $us ?>">
</form>

<script>
     $(function () {
            $('body').on('submit', '#my-form', function (e) {
                var mensaje = document.getElementById('message').value;
                var nombre = document.getElementById('nombre').value;
                var idEmitter = document.getElementById('myId').value;
                var idReceiver = document.getElementById('idEmitter').value;

                var dataen = 'message='+mensaje +'&nombre='+nombre +'&myId='+idEmitter +'&idEmitter='+idReceiver;

                $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    dataType: "html",
                    url:'inser.php',
                    data:dataen
                });
                return false;
            })
        })
</script>
```

Comment: Why would that work better than the inline `onsubmit="..."` attribute? From my reading of the question the Ajax request is getting to the server, and then a PHP error occurs.

Comment: What's the output of `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: I forgot to add script tags around the javascript, just updated my answer.

Comment: on inser.php? iif that's your question print a horrible `array(0) { } `

Comment: what i want to do whit ajax? because i have an id over the url, this id is important for the function of my "chat" someone told me this.. `For now you can fix it by changing the form's action
For the url to match the id = X
And the X you put it with php` but i don'w know how to do this

Answer (score 0):

try this :

html :

```
<form onsubmit='return onSubmit(this)'>
</form>
```

js:

```
function onSubmit( form ){
     $.ajax({
                    type:'POST',
                    dataType: "json",
                    url:'inser.php',
                    data:{data : JSON.stringify( $(form).serializeArray() )},
                   success : function(data){
                     alert("Success");                 
                    }
                });

  return false; //don't submit
}
```

in your php :

```
 $formdata = json_decode($_POST['data'],true); // this contains your form data
```

**EDIT**

sorry my mistake i forget that `form.serializearray()` will return `json array` with name value pair

i created a fiddle for your fix : https://jsfiddle.net/9gg81m0e/

> In that fiddle i used "json" as key so that the jsfiddle will
>   understand the request  for your case just send only the result object
>   and use post method on the other end with form input name as a key
>   parameter

also you can always find the error in js code with browser console (f9)

Comment: look i put my code in the cloud https://mega.nz/#!DlVU2SQI!4pTf20qUVo1xikWhhseeDw1XTXvQKtha4p8iu6SjWoI

Comment: doesn't insert anithing in my db and in inser.php the errors still being the same

Comment: please!! I'll be very greatful

Comment: look i share the complete project and db, In the end it's just test https://mega.nz/#!S1Nz0ZxD!e8_X8OLFen55-tXzTJAf63lCRoyOVW53rUJg6cQ9Ja4
 the user is cesg.dav@hotmail.com and pass cesar

Comment: my code is working all you have missed is comma in ajax and a close bracket in the window.onload check it

Comment: i'll try your answer

Comment: press f9 and try to find is there any error on ajax

Comment: in the inspector of mozilla appear this in the console `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Comment: your jquery is not defined paste this in above all `script` tag `<script
     src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
     integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: `The hash contained in the integrity attribute could not be decoded`

Comment: `None of the "sha256" hashes in the integrity attribute match the contents of the subroutine.`

Comment: in tat case try this : `<script src ="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>` or remove the `integrity` in the above script tag

Comment: sorry, but no, doesn't insert in the data base

Comment: just saying "data is not inserted" is not helpfull..... is that your ajax working first is it sending form data in post ? and can you able to receive the data in php ?

Comment: ok, the data is sending by GET (i suppose) , in URL is like thise `http://localhost/talvez%20empresa/chat/index.php?message=asdasd&nombre=Demon+Tech+System&submit=Send+it&idReceiver=1&idEmitter=3`, in my db doesn't have nothing new

Comment: comment your `window.onload` function and try clicking submit and check whether there is a data processing just like you enter but instead of index.php check for inser.php

Comment: Please do not give up haha ​​I just need this to finish it